# Special Case of the Central Limit Theorem for Discrete Uniform Variables?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I have $X = \sum_{i = 0}^n x_i$, where each $x_i$ is a die roll that takes on any of the values $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]$ with equal probability.

I think that, according to the C.L.T, at $n \rightarrow \infty$ the variable $X$ will become normally distributed.

**What I'm wondering:** is there any proof of the Central Limit Theorem for this special case -- perhaps more accessible than the general proof?

**What I've tried:** If we allow dice with a large number of sides to simplify things, I think the number of ways to roll $k$ die and sum to $m$ is $\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}$ (stars-and-bars). The total number of ways to roll the die will be $k^n$, so:

$$
P(X = m) = \frac{\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}}{k^n}
$$

But this becomes zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: The CLT states that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ becomes normally distributed, *not* $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Comment: The proof for the classical version on Wiki is accessible if you accept that the characteristic function determines the distribution. Not sure it gets any simpler.

Comment: Indeed there is no reason to expect a simpler proof in the specific case of random variables uniform on {1,2,...,6}.